# Почему не получается скомпилировать приложение в MonoDevelop?

Tags: c#, linux, ubuntu, mono, monodevelop

Я установил Monodevelop и .net 5.0 sdk. СОздал обычное консольное приложение, но оно не компилируется(Monodevelop ругается на все и даже на using System;)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Попытка скомпилировать в терминале:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Попытка скомпилировать в monodevelop:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ошибка после использования в термилане dotnet restore:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Ошибка, после создания проекта в терминале dotnet new console:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: где попытки компилировать? Какие ошибки компиляции? Просто в командной строке скомпилируется?

Comment: Нет, не компилируется. Пишет о том что не может восстановить пакеты Nuget(при этом в самом monodevelop эта функция отмечена серым цветом, тоесть нельзя её использовать)

Comment: `dotnet restore` в терминале запускали?

Comment: В терминале скомпилировалось после этого, но в monodevelop - нет. При этом файл, в котором происходила компиляция называется netcoreapp1.1(хотя вроде такой версии нету). Компилировал с помощью msbuild Lab1.csproj. ПРи этом до этого monodevelop пишет "Не удалось восстановить пакеты".

Comment: вероятно вы создавали проект через monodevelop и он почему то не той версии проект создал. Попробуйте создать второй проект чисто из консоли - `dotnet new console` - [тут есть примеры команд](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code)

Comment: Ошибка не ушла. Но в терминале этот проект тоже нельзя скомпилировать. Ошибка, пишет что требует .NEt Framework??

Comment: Вы пробовали создать проект через консоль?

Comment: Да. Я его создал через консоль и вышло то что в моем предыдущем сообщении

Comment: а разве `monodevelop` поддерживает .net 5? он же не обновлялся уже 2 года

Comment: НУ проблема только в mono и monodevelop. Компилировать удалось лишь с помощью dotnet build(причем без каких либо проблем.) Мое решение - не использовать monodevelop, а использовать visual studio code..

Comment: Если ищите альтернативу VS на линукс, рассмотрите Rider